# S3Client->GetObject() never returns or throws an exception if given a non-existent key

Tags: php, amazon-s3

`AWS S3Client->getObject()` never returns and never throws an exception if I request a key that doesn't exist.  I suspect that other S3Client methods have the same problem when given a non-existent key.

However, if I configure the S3Client with `'debug' => true`, it will throw `Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception` when the file is not found, which is acceptable.

Here is a test case I wrote:

```
protected function _test_s3_client_get($unit, $key) {
    $provider = CredentialProvider::ini(NULL, APPPATH . 'config/aws.ini');
    $provider = CredentialProvider::memoize($provider);
    $client = new S3Client([
        'region' => 'us-east-1',
        'version' => '2006-03-01',
        'credentials' => $provider,
        // 'debug' => ['logfn' => [$this, '_noop']]
        // 'debug' => true,
    ]);
    try {
        $result = $client->getObject(array(
            'Bucket' => 'mybucket',
            'Key'=> $key,
            ));
    } catch (S3Exception $e) {
        error_log($e);
    }
    $unit->run(isset($result['Body']), true, "Got $key");
}
```

If `'debug' => true`, the S3Client dumps a huge amount of data in the response regardless of whether or not it found the file.  As a workaround, I can set the `debug` option to call an empty function with the debug output.  Nevertheless, this does not look like a permanent solution.

Has anyone else encountered this problem?  Is there a better workaround?

Comment: If there is no result I would expect `$result` to be `null` is that not the case?

Comment: @Pitchinnate It never returns.

Comment: Hmm yeah looking at the documentation there is no return error for the `getObject()` method. There is a `NoSuchKey` error for `GetObjectAcl()` so maybe you could call that first to make sure the key exists then call `getObject()`

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#getobjectacl

Comment: I've written same code using aws-sdk 3.20.13 and it works for me...

Comment: Btw, does your policy contains `s3:GetObject` action?

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether the key (filename) exist or not using this function before you do any kind of operation.

> $doesFileExist = $client->doesObjectExist($bucket, $key);

This will True or False

Answer (score 0):

We use `"aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.8.22"` and we have exception `NoSuchKeyException` in such cases. Here our code:

```
private function fileExists($bucket, $key)
{
    try {
        $o = $this->s3->getObject([
            'Bucket' => $bucket,
            'Key' => $key,
        ]);
        return $o;
    } catch (\Aws\S3\Exception\NoSuchKeyException $e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The only one difference in `"aws/aws-sdk-php" "3.20.13"` is that it throws not `NoSuchKeyException` but `Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception`.

Btw, check your bucket policy. My policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ACZ",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my.own.bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Also it works for me with version `"aws/aws-sdk-php" "3.20.13"` and throw exception `\Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception`.

Comment: Thank you, @VladimirKovpak. I'll look up the bucket policy when I get to work tomorrow.  I didn't set up S3 and don't have a direct AWS account.  I depend on a colleague for that.